# Dreamweaver CS4; space to right of page

Tags: html, margin, dreamweaver, space, cs4

White space problem in Dreamweaver CS4 this time. I designed a page with a background image of 1024 x 1024. The page looks fine in the design window. When I preview in browser or upload
to server the page has about 200 px of white space to the right.  I've set the margins to '0'
for the top, left, right and  bottom. The space remains.  Next instead of using 1024 image as a background image I inserted into an AP Div. Same result. Just for chuckles I went in HTML I changed the margins to 1, I still got 200 px to the right.  After much hard work on the site design it's very frustrating to have some mystery element destroy my design. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Digital D

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: it's pretty hard to understand your problem, what do you mean with 'white space'. What exactly to you expect screens with more than 1024 pixels to show you when the browser window is wider than 1024 pixels? What do you want this space to do?

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the width of that `div` set properly. I imagine you would see that in dreamweaver.  Perhaps it is just that you haven't properly set the style properly for the background-image

Here's how I would set it for a full background image:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Solution</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="maindiv" style="background-image: url('image.jpg'); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
         <p style="color: white">This is the content of the div </p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```